# Add friend error in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I can log in from one user, when i try logging in with other user accounts, i get the following error

> ```
> Friend matching query does not exist.
> ```

below is my views.py. i get an error on the line 7

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home/home.html'
    def get(self, request):
        form = HomeForm()
        posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created')
        users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)
        friend = Friend.objects.get(current_user=request.user) ...
        friends = friend.users.all()
        args = {
            'form': form, 'posts': posts, 'users': users, 'friends': friends
        }
    return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

Comment: The message is clear: there is no `Friend` that matches `current_user=request.user`

Comment: what do i do? any suggestionS? i am new to this, please help

Comment: If you want suggestions then you should show your models, and explain what the querysets are supposed to be.

Comment: Post your models

Answer (score 0):

[`QuerySet.get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#get) raises exception if it does not find one and only one entry in the database with the given conditions.

You can do:

```
try:
    friend = Friend.objects.get(current_user=request.user)
except Friend.DoesNotExist:
    # handle the error here, maybe add the friend? 
except Friend. MultipleObjectsReturned:
    # multiple friends
```

or:

```
current_user_friends = Friend.objects.filter(current_user=request.user)
if not current_user_friends.exists():
    # handle the error here, maybe add the friend?
else:
    friend = current_user_friends[0]
    # at this point, request.user can have more than one friend
```

given that you are looking for `request.user`'s friends, you can try:

```
friends = request.user.friends.all()
```

assuming that your `Friend` model is something like:

```
class Friend(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, ..., related_name='friends')
    ...
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

also make shure that you makemigrations and migrate after adding your Friend model